# Laravel & HTML files

Tags: php, html, laravel-4

I have bought Ninja Media Script template in order to start my own site.
But, I didn't know it was made in Laravel framework which I know nothing about.
**When I do Inspect element on my site,** **I can see HTML file structure** and within I would have no problem editing the sections of my website.But, in my website folders there are only php files with no HTML code, and it really bothers me.

Lets say I want to edit **category Home within nav bar** . This is what I see on Inspect element for the category Home in nav bar :

```
<li class="active"> 
   <a href="mysite">
     <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
     <span>Home<span>
   <a/>
```

In HTML/CSS templates I would just change "Home" within span and new name would appear.But I cant find that file in HTML format, only php with no html code in it.
So, i search for the file where the class for category Home is located.
**Search results : master.blade.php**

This is what I see in master.blade.php for category Home :

```
<li class="@if(Request::is('/')Request::is('category/*'))active@endif">
    <a href="{{ URL::to('/') }}">
        <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
        <span>{{ Lang::get('lang.home') }}</span>
    </a>
    <div class="nav-border-bottom"></div>
</li>
```

My question is, can I somehow locate or switch to see my webpage files as HTML documents, to see HTML structure not those php files with a lot of functions, arrays and Good knows what else? It would be so much easier for me to edit it, since I don't know PHP.

Thank You in advance and I hope someone understands the question?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. You could..theroetically....open each page individually, view the source, and save the page. However, that may be super tedious. Laravel is extremely easy to learn and the documentation is great. Why not give yourself a challange!

Comment: @Ohgodwhy ern Thank You guys for your answers. I will try and learn it. Can You just answer me one more question. Here is the link to my website visitrovinj.com/30posto.  I have tried to add one more category to navbar. If I for example, use the code that I wrote above for Home in master.blade.php, and copy it right under the same line of code, would I see 2 Home categories. Because I have tried that and that didnt happen. Have I done something wrong or ?

Comment: "It would be so much easier for me to edit it, since I don't know PHP." If you don't know PHP, you shouldn't be modifying a site that's built in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I would learn the basic PHP and HTML if you want to do some development. You can probably find some PHP-in-60-mins videos on youtube. So here the Lang is a Laravel Facade (class) that calls its method get() to get the home variable value. If you installed Laravel, you should look for resources/lang folder. There's probably a file that contains all the language strings.

To answer your question in your comment: you can try copy the entire `<li>` block underneath the first `<li>` block. Or try copy the `<a>` block underneath the first `<a>` block but within the `<li>` tag. You need to read some use Chrome's dev tool or Firebug to see how the elements are being structured according to their CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The script must have a documentation, if you only need to change the styles  here is the laravel explanation for laravel 4,off course is a plus to know php but for change the style you don't need to.

https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates

anyway if you have that kind of styles doubts on a bought script you can contact the tutorial/documentation/support of the place you bought the script